# How can I refactor my code using functions?

Tags: python

It is a simple maze game I did for school. I have tried different solutions but still cant figure out how. I don't necessarily need a full solution; any tips would help.

```
x = 1
y = 1
valid_selection = True

while True:
    if x == 1 and y == 1:
        if valid_selection == True:
            print("You can travel: (N)orth.")
        valid_selection = True
        choice = input("Direction: ")
        if choice.lower() == "n":
            y += 1
        else:
            print("Not a valid direction!")
            valid_selection = False
    elif x == 1 and y == 2:
        if valid_selection == True:
            print("You can travel: (N)orth or (E)ast or (S)outh.")
        valid_selection = True
        choice = input("Direction: ")
        if choice.lower() == "n":
            y += 1
        elif choice.lower() == "e":
            x += 1
        elif choice.lower() == "s":
            y -= 1
        else:
            print("Not a valid direction!")
            valid_selection = False
    elif x == 3 and y == 1:
        print("Victory!")
        break
```

Comment: What do you mean "express my code using functions"?  What's your goal and what have you tried so far?

Comment: created a function that validate the move or return "not a valid move", the maze basically have a grid of 3x3 so for each direction i will increment or decrease x and y, but it cannot move everywhere so i have to make this checks for coordinate 1,1 for instance, or 2,3 etc, by function does not store the value and ir resets always to 1,1 and that is my first issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your function recieving `x` and `y` as parameters, removing the While True and replacing it with its creation, like `def MyFunc(x,y)`, putting the `valid_selection` variable inside it and removing `x` and `y` attributions. And then you call it in the end of the code passing `1` and `1` as your desired parameters, like `MyFunc(1,1)`

Comment: My desired parameters can's be assigned as x and y, the only parameter i can use to direct the x and y is choice input

Comment: Well, you're using x=1 and y=1 to initialize your game before any choice inputs are made, so MyFunc(1,1) would only do the same, redirect you to the same if (the first one). I guess I didn't get what you meant, then.

Comment: you are correct, but i the while loop because the program have to prompt for another move until reaches the victory

Comment: You could create some other flag outside the ifs and set it  `True`, and then set it to `False` when it reaches victory. Something like `flag = True`, `while(flag):` and then `flag = False` after `print("Victory!")`

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to create a function. 
First, you need to abstract what your program do. The name of the function have to express this. 
Second, you need to know what are the inputs. In your case the input must be x and y, or the proper names to these input.

The answer which your function will return is a important thing to know. The user will see a print or the user of the function will use a number, string or other object to feed other function.

I hope this not confusing.